# PowerBI MicrosoftAzureConsumptionInsights - changing query to get more than 2 months

Tags: azure, powerbi-desktop, m

I am using PowerBI to analyze Cost data from Azure. I am making a direct connection and pulling in data by: **opening PowerBI | Get Data | Online Services | Microsoft Azure Consumption Insights (Beta)** This works, however, I am only able to see two months of data and ideally I'd like to see 6. After a lot of searching the general consensus from other users seems to be using the advanced editor to tweak the query by adding "optionalParameters" and specifying the number of months... I came across a few other sites where users were experiencing the same issue but the suggestions didn't work. I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I'm going to post the query string and below that list out the URLs containing suggestions I've already tried.

```
let
    enrollmentNumber = "xxxxxxx",
    optionalParameters = [ numberOfMonth = 6, dataType="DetailCharges" ],
    Source = MicrosoftAzureConsumptionInsights.Tables(enrollmentNumber, optionalParameters),
    usagedetails = Source{[Key="usagedetails"]}[Data],
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(usagedetails,{{"Tags", Json.Document}}),
    #"Expanded Tags" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Parsed JSON", "Tags", {"environment", "application", "costCenter", "owner"}, {"Tags.environment", "Tags.application", "Tags.costCenter", "Tags.owner"})
in
    #"Expanded Tags"
```

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Azure-consumption-insights-get-more-than-two-month-usage-details/td-p/541413
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-desktop-and-getting-multiple-months-in-one-row-from-the/td-p/50585
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Extend-the-Azure-consupmtion-data/td-p/444508
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-azure-consumption-insights

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case and now have a solution to this problem.

First - The version of PowerBI had to be upgraded to the latest version. The version I upgraded to is: Version: 2.75.5649.961 64-bit (November 2019)

Second - Microsoft Azure Consumption Insights is being phased out and is being replaced by Azure Cost Management. This won't work with Consumption insights.

I was able to increase the number of months by:

1. Get Data | Azure | Azure Cost Management
2. Fill in the required information specifying number of months.

[Get Data Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q02iZ.png)